# How to iterate through multiple select options using forEach to get innerText values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach

How do you iterate, using forEach (or a similar modern browser method) to get the innerText value of each select option? This throws an error. `Uncaught TypeError: intervals.forEach is not a function`

```
let intervals = document.querySelector("#edit_amenity_hour_interval").options;
intervals.forEach(interval => {
    console.log(interval.innerText)
})
```

Comment: Can you paste your html code also?

Comment: Put a console.log for `document.querySelector("#edit_amenity_hour_interval")` see if that has an `option` iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.from`, because options returns collection, not array

```
let intervals = Array.from(document.querySelector("#edit_amenity_hour_interval").options)
```